# Résumé upload functionality in Drupal 7

Tags: 7

Is there any module available in Drupal 7 for getting a résumé uploading functionality? I need a form with a couple of text fields and a file upload field that accepts files of .doc, .odt, and .docx formats. My requirement is to send an email also with the attachments, and also see the list of submitted résumés.

Comment: I investigated it a few months ago, and every solution I found implied some server setup. AFAIK, there is no Drupal module supporting this, even with all the server stuff deployed.

Comment: @Countzero How did you finally managed it?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question : 'resume' means job document right ? I thought about resuming interrupted downloads, so my answer is irrelevant. Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a *Résumé* content type. Add your text fields and a file field to this content type. Set your permissions accordingly, allowing whichever user roles you want (or anonymous) to create this content.

This will allow people to upload their resumes.

Get the [Rules](http://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module and create a rule a bit like follows

**Events**

*Node* - After saving new content

**Conditions**

*Node* - Content is of type:  Résumé

**Actions**

*System* - Send mail

You can use Token to put content fields into the email, but I'm not sure if you can put links to the file.  If not, you can at least put a link to the content that contains the file.

Lastly...use [Views](http://www.drupal.org/project/views) and create a simple view that shows *Résumé* content -From here, get  sorted however you want.

For extra points, you could also use the [Flag](http://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module to flag résumés (e.g. follow up, spam, not useful and so forth), and then create more views based on those flags (so you can only see useful résumés for exampleetc).

Answer (score -2):

thats baked into d7 core already. just add a filefield and specify the file types.

Comment: The question is about RESUME uploading.

Comment: @dubai - How is it possible?My requirement is to  send an email and also see the list of submitted resumes

Comment: Canceled my downvote. See above why.

Comment: user7282 you did not specify that in your initial question. maybe try rephrasing you question to include all of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @dubai There's no need to be rude.  Your answer could also have included more information for unseasoned Drupallers.  Remember, other people learning Drupal may stumble across this post - Saying "Just add a field" might not actually be helpful at all, even if it is the right answer.